Field of positive characteristic not perfect in which every polynomial is reducible
It is well-known that, in a real closed  field $K$,  every polynomial of degree>2 is reducible in $K$. But in this case the characteristic of $K$ is zero.
My question is: there exists a field $F$ of characteristic $p>0$ not perfect and a positive integer $n=n(F)$ such that all polynomials of degree$>n$ are reducible in $F$.

See this post, which is closely related.

@DietrichBurde thanks. I ask for a field which is not perfect

@DietrichBurde which one?

@DietrichBurde in this example $F$ is union (ordered) of finite fields(so perfects fields) which is hence perfect

I think this is not possible. If $F$ is an imperfect field of characteristic $p>0$, there is an element $a\in F$ without a $p$-th root, and then the polynomials $X^{p^k}-a$ are irreducible for all $k$.
Hence the situation is as follows. If $F$ is an arbitrary field, then there exists a maximal degree $n$ of irreducible polynomials over $F$ if and only if $F$ is algebraically closed, in which case $n=1$, or real-closed, in which case $n=2$.

If we assume that polynomials are such that of degree prime with p
